# Domain not authorized to use PDF Embed API though listed as allowed in Adobe console

Tags: html, pdf, xampp, adobe-embed-api

I am using the Adobe PDF Embed API to display PDFs on my web client.

For development I'm using XAMPP with virtual hosts.
Since I set up xampp to use SSL encryption locally, I can not get the Embed API to work anymore.

I have an API Client Id and the allowed domains set to my local development domain.
But when requesting the API, it says the domain would not be authorized.
I tried setting the allowed domains in the Adobe console to the VirtualHost ServerName as well as using localhost as allowed domain. But neither is working.

Anybody got a guess why it is not working?

Comment: localhost should be allowed but my main concern is that you wrote "I tried setting the allowed ***domains*** in the Adobe console to the VirtualHost ServerName". With Embed API, only ***one*** domain would be allowed. Are you sure you are in the right location for Embed API credentials?

Comment: I set the domains subsequently, so I tried only one domain at a time. And I am sure to be in the right location, as I entered the domain when adding the Embed API to my project.

Comment: Ok - I know that sometimes we have problems when the domain for a credential gets edited. You can get as many credentials as you want so I suggest creating a new one and try that.

Comment: Creating a new project with new credentials did the job, thank you joel!
Important to note: using localhost as domain did not work. I had to use the Servername of my local virtual host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

As it seems, the Adobe Console has difficulties when the allowed domains are edited. So I created a new project, added the API and used the ServerName of my local XAMPP Virtual Host (without the subdomain) as the allowed domain.